# My machine language outputs gobblygook in pep9. What am i not getting?

Tags: assembly, pep8-assembly

D1 00 0D F1 FC 16 D1 00 0E F1 FC 16 D1 00 0F F1 FC 16 00 48 69 33 zz

Im just using the example to learn. This is supposed to say "hi!" in the output. It, however, says symbols that i cant even copy and paste. Are the numbers being combined somehow? referencing junk data? i thought i cleared it.

A simple correction will do, im not getting it.

Comment: There should be a disassembler for PEP9; most people don't read raw machine code but instead look at the corresponding asm instructions.

Comment: In addition to what Peter said, I'm guessing the string you are trying to output is "Hi!" (48 69 33) not "hi!".  And while I'm not familiar with pep9, I wonder if your text is supposed to have a null at the end to terminate the string.  Failing to do that could result in "Hi!FollowedByABunchOfRandomGarbage"